# blocking queue in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, multithreading, client

I want to implement a custom TCP Client in Unity that has separate threads for sending and receiving certain messages.
For sending, the Client is supposed to have a **blocking queue**, that

- receives messages from other threads and
- the message-sending thread polls messages from the queue and sends them - but blocks when the queue is empty.

In on .net 3.5 I do not have access to BlockingCollection.

I would have expected that some implementation existed.
So far I have found implementation that simply lock on a queue, which from my understanding is not sufficient.

How could I implement this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Brief search reveals dozen of implementations, duplicate SO questions included.

Comment: This question is not about game development, its about a library recommendation for c#

Comment: Sorry, I saw lots of questions related specifically to unity scripting, so i concluded this would be the right place to ask.
Peter, so should i rather post it on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @wondra which search terms you have used on so? I havent found an implementation there.

Comment: If you need a `ConcurrentQueue`, just create a class that wraps `Queue` and uses `lock()` to block the thread.

Comment: "c sharp blocking queue implementation", then is it just click the first link and copy-paste. There is even some discussion on blocking queue implementations.

Comment: @Lasse That won't do in this case. They don't want a *concurrent* queue, they want a *blocking* queue. The OP wants to suspend their message handling thread when the message queue is empty and have it resume the moment something is added to the queue. `lock` alone won't help with this.

Comment: @IARI while programming questions that are not specific to gaming are a better match for stackoverflow, product recommendations are unfortunately off topic on both sites, so this question would likely get closed on SO.

Comment: I think you can accomplish that "wake on new data" behaviour with Monitor.Pulse, right? It's been a little while since I did much threading so I can't recall if there are better primitives for this.

Comment: @Peter I thought this would be a good spot, since the question pretty much unity-specific, particularly whenever one is stuck to dotnet 3.5 it was usually always unity.
Setting aside that i pretty much asked for some existing implementation (my bad) - is it still not a good fit for gamedev.stackexchange?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I just read some more about what belongs here, and of course you are right, it would be better suited for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This implementation shared by Stephen Toub is literally the second Google search result for "blocking queue c#"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/04/12/blocking-queues/) so don't underestimate the value of doing your own research. ;)

Code reproduced below in case the link ever breaks. Comments are mine:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class BlockingQueue<T> : IEnumerable<T>    
{    
    private int _count = 0;

    private Queue<T> _queue = new Queue<T>();

    public T Dequeue()    
    {    
        lock (_queue)    
        {   
            // If we have items remaining in the queue, skip over this. 
            while (_count <= 0) 
            {
                // Release the lock and block on this line until someone
                // adds something to the queue, resuming once they 
                // release the lock again.
                Monitor.Wait(_queue);
            }

            _count--;

            return _queue.Dequeue();    
        }    
    }

    public void Enqueue(T data)    
    {    
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(“data”);

        lock (_queue)    
        {    
            _queue.Enqueue(data);

            _count++;

            // If the consumer thread is waiting for an item
            // to be added to the queue, this will move it
            // to a waiting list, to resume execution
            // once we release our lock.
            Monitor.Pulse(_queue);    
        }    
    }

    // Lets the consumer thread consume the queue with a foreach loop.
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()    
    {    
        while (true) yield return Dequeue();    
    }    

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()    
    {    
        return ((IEnumerable<T>)this).GetEnumerator();    
    }    
}
```